# How can i validate image content using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Example i'm uploading a file type image. And the image must be an specific animal, example : dogs. So how can i validate that the picture uploaded is dogs (not any different species or something else) using jQuery ?
P/s : This is the first time i asking a question in this site. I'm not good as English, so apologizing for my English description. Thank you for concern !

Comment: This isn't possible with jQuery: the technology you're looking for is an image classifier, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tillson said, you are looking for an image classifier.

One that seems to be popular is [tensorflow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js). You can see a cool tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/tensorflow-js-real-time-object-detection-in-10-lines-of-code-baf15dfb95b2), and there is even a package called [tensorflow-animals](https://github.com/aaronice/tensorflow-animals) which has been trained to detect animals, including dogs!